# Selecting rows of data between time and date range in tall array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm applying tall arrays to a couple of .csv files. The tall array looks like:

```
  Timestamp           wind_spd_sd    wind_spd_mx
___________________    ___________    ___________

04/03/2016 00:00:01    0.57576        4.1        
04/03/2016 00:03:01    0.53692        3.1        
04/03/2016 00:06:01    0.35642        4.2        
04/03/2016 00:09:01    0.63012        4.9        
04/03/2017 00:12:01    0.30357        3.7        
04/03/2017 00:15:01    0.53442        10        
:                      :              :
:                      :              :
```

I want to be able to select the rows of data between specific dates and times. I came across "timerange" which is used for timetables and used it as:

```
S1 = timerange('01/01/2015 08:00:00','12/18/2016 12:00:00')

S2 = tt{S1,:}
```

but had the error: "Subscripting using TIMERANGE is only supported for selecting rows of a timetable."

I then tried using datenum as:

```
t_start = datenum('04/03/2014 00:00:01', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');

t_end = datenum('04/03/2015 00:03:01', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');

rows = find(tt.Timestamp>t_start)
```

and the error was:
"Undefined function 'find' for input arguments of type 'tall'"

I'm not 100% sure if the problem is definitely tall arrays or that I'm making a mistake in how I use these functions. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve here with tall array?

Comment: If the posted answer solves your problem, consider [marking it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of the answer, to turn it green so that the community may know that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with your use of the `timerange` function. However, you need to convert your `tall` array to a `timetable`, which is a specific data type. Do this first:

```
TT = table2timetable(tt);
S1 = timerange('01/01/2015 08:00:00','12/18/2016 12:00:00')
S2 = TT(S1,:);
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.