# joining rows in tall arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-table

I have a large set of data, its first row look like

```
02.06.2016 11;04;30.832404 1.2 3.3
02.06.2016 11;04;30.832504 2.4 2.3
02.06.2016 11;04;30.832604 6.1 7.1
```

I'm using tall arrays in MATLAB. I want to be able to use the timerange function to select data between different time ranges (see my previous questions: 
[Selecting rows of data between time and date range in tall array in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663882/selecting-rows-of-data-between-time-and-date-range-in-tall-array-in-matlab)
 ).

However, if I'm not mistaken the time and the date must be in the same row. I was therefore, trying to combine the two into one row. I've tried different functions such as "join", but I was unable to find anything that works with tall arrays. Is there a way round this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The [`timerange`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerange.html) function does not support tall timetables currently (R2017a).

Still, it's worth your time to create a tall [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) variable in your table using your existing variables of time information since that should make indexing easier.